# App for Reading - iPad & PDF

Tags: ipad, pdf

I am searching for a application with the following functionality, but cant find one:

I want to read PDFs. I want to highlight some text from time to time or add a note (with its timestamp). The summary of all highlights / notes should aggregated together so there is some special page(s) / section that contain only the highlighted text and notes.

Does something like this exist? I know there are dozens of apps for reading itself, but i am not sure whether there is app that allows me to list in "my highlighted content" only.

Answer (score 1):

The [Amazon Kindle app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kindle-read-books-ebooks-magazines/id302584613) can do this. It's free and you can add your own PDFs to it.

When you highlight some text, an option to write a note is presented (the icon with the pencil):

[image]

Then you can go to "My Notebook" to have an overview of all text snippets and your corresponding notes:

[image: My Notebook screen]